# How can i set auto cache and reindex using cron

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, cron, reindex

I need to set magento all cache and magento reindex automatically, how can i done by using cron.

Answer (score 2):

for reindexing you can use below cron

```
0 0 * * * php -f /path_to_your_magento/shell/indexer.php reindex
```

for caching you can add below cron

```
0 0 * * * rm -rf /path_to_your_magento/var/cache/*
```

Comment: what is : rm    &    -f   ?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a class that specifically handles command line scripts. The Magento bootstrap can be handled via the Shell Abstract script inside of your shell/ folder.

```
<?php

include_once 'abstract.php';

class JohnG_Shell_Cron extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {

    public function run() {
        $this->_clearindex();
        $this->_clearCache();
    }

    protected function _clearindex() {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
            $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
            $process->reindexAll();
            }
    }

    protected function _clearCache() {
        $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
            foreach($allTypes as $type => $cache) {
                   Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
            }
    }
}
```

Now setup your cron like this:

> 0 0-23/2 * * * php -f /path/to/your/magento/shell/johngscript.php

Comment: which location i paste this code

Comment: Inside shell folder, this script work with magento 1x,if this help please upvote answer